# Photons - difference

Tags: photons

Is there a difference between an observed photon from the sun and an observed photon from the sun that has bounced off the moon?

Is there a difference between an observed photon from the sun and an observed photon from the Andromeda galaxy?

Is an observed photon from the Andromeda galaxy actually a piece of the Andromeda galaxy?

Comment: No, all photons (and particles, of one type) are the same. If they were not, we wouldn't have been able to predict anything in physics because every other experiment would give a different result.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a unique print on a single photon of the source from which a photon is emitted. Of course, in general, different photons are different in the sense that they can have different frequencies and polarizations. But, given that we are comparing the photons of the same frequency and polarization, a photon from the Andromeda would be exactly identical to the photon from the Sun.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a photon as an agreement between to atoms, however far apart, to exchange energy through the vacuum electromagnetic field. The origin could be one thing that kind of makes the photons unique, like 2 guitar players, the notes sound the same but come from different directions. But essentially if they are the same frequency (but in general their frequencies are slightly different) they are the same physical phenomenon.

A photon is energy not mass, so it is not a piece.

Answer (score 0):

The photon is an elementary particle in the [standard model of particle physics .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

None of the particles in the table can carry an identity characteristic, as they  are point particles and cannot be distinguished when in an ensemble, unless the mechanism of their generation is observed or can be deduced from the behavior of the ensemble.

Example: a generated spectrum of photons from stars with characteristic  excitations of atoms are [used to learn about the motion of stars.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-do-we-know-about-redshift)

[image]

So one can know if a photon registered on  a film has high probability to have come from Andromeda if it is a part of a recorded spectrum from Andromeda.

Comment: Can you please tell me if we can say depending on the momentum of a photon whether it came from a certain direction? Is there an experiment that would show the direction the photon came from?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei all spectra of stars, of course, , within  the error of the optics . Single  photon laser experiments? https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/